# Malloc in array gives Segmentation fault

Tags: c, malloc

In my attempt to understand malloc and structs I have come across an error I do not understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct match
{
   int round;
} match;

void foo(match *matches) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      matches = (match *) realloc(matches, i + 1);
      matches[i].round = i + 1;
   }
}

int main()
{
   match *matches;

   matches = (match *) malloc(0);

   foo(matches);

   free(matches);

   return(0);
}
```

So in my attempt to fill this array of matches dynamicaly it fails

Comment: why malloc(0) ?

Comment: `matches = (match *) realloc(matches, i + 1);` What do you want for this line?

Answer (score 2):

Your `foo` function is very flawed. First, the parameter passes a copy of the `matches` pointer, so when you realloc, that updates the `foo` `matches` pointer, but not the `matches` pointer in `main`. This may cause problems with the `free` in main. You need to change the parameter to `foo` to be a double pointer: `void foo(match **matches)`. Then to realloc, `*matches = realloc(...`

Next, the second parameter to `realloc` is a size. But `i + 1` isn't going to be big enough for a full copy of the `match` struct. You probably meant to do something like `sizeof(struct match) * (i + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to above answer. Good Explanation...
Please check the error from realloc as well before using the memory,

Modified the program

```
void foo(match **matches) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      *matches = realloc(*matches, (i+1) * sizeof(match));
      ...
   }
}

int main()
{
...

   foo(&matches);
...
}
```